# dynamically add checkboxes to frame on form vba

Tags: vba, excel

how can you add multiple checkboxes to a userForm Frame? This seems like a trivial thing to do, but my code is only generating a checkbox for last item in array.

```
Private Sub btnGenerate_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim lic As licence
Dim temp As Variant
Dim desc As String
Dim chkbox As MSForms.CheckBox
Dim str As String

For Each lic In licenceCollection
    temp = lic.getClause
Next lic

For i = LBound(temp) To UBound(temp)
    'Debug.Print temp(i)
    desc = "Future-Sampling " & i
    'Utility.createCheckBoxes temp(i), desc
    Set chkbox = licenceForm.resultFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", desc)
    chkbox.Caption = temp(i)
    chkbox.Value = desc
    chkbox.Width = "450"
    chkbox.Height = "50"
    chkbox.WordWrap = True
    chkbox.Value = False
    chkbox.GroupName = "Future Sampling"
Next
End Sub
```

Any suggestions here much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need an i on your last Next...

Comment: @Rdster "Next " + variable serves just for retaining value of i outside the scope of loop.

Comment: @holmicz - It has nothing to do with scope.  There's no function difference between `Next` and `Next i` at all.  It's purely a matter of preference and coding style.

Comment: @Rdster You are right, I don't know where I got it from. :-)

Comment: Actually @Rdster *isn't* right. Adding the counter name to the end of `Next` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Except help noobs keep their code easier to follow and read.

Answer (score 1):

They're all being created just fine, but the reason you can only see the last one is that they're all stacking on top of each other in the default position when they're added.  You need to position them with the `.Top` and `.Left` properties:

```
Dim xPos As Long
For i = LBound(temp) To UBound(temp)
    desc = "Future-Sampling " & i
    Set chkbox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", desc)
    With chkbox
        .Top = xPos
        .Caption = temp(i)
        .Value = desc
        .Width = 450
        .Height = 24
        .WordWrap = True
        .Value = False
        .GroupName = "Future Sampling"
        xPos = xPos + 24
    End With
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you are adding components on the same position, therefore it is overlapping and you are seeing only last one, isn't it? You need to adjust `left` and `top` coordinate, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, that seemed to do the trick! I never figured this cont

Revised code snippet below,

```
      For i = LBound(temp) To UBound(temp)
                desc = "Future-Sampling " & i
                Set chkbox = Me.resultFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", desc)
                With chkbox
                    .Top = xPos
                    .Caption = temp(i)
                    .Value = desc
                    .Width = 450
                    .Height = 24
                    .WordWrap = True
                    .Value = False
                    .GroupName = "Future Sampling"
                    xPos = xPos + 24
                End With


        Next i
```